# SEO есть, результата нет

Tags: seo, интернет-магазин, продвижение, раскрутка

хэшкодовцы!

Не сочтите за рекламу или еще что то там, но у меня есть [мой проект](http://boo.dp.ua), которым я занимаюсь и пытаюсь продвинуть в поисковиках. Прошел месяц, как я этим занимаюсь, но результаты пока что не впечатляют :(

После 2 недель раскрутки начали появляться переходы с гугла и дошли до 10 переходов в день. Но, считаю, что этого точно не достаточно.

Если есть здесь люди, разбирающиеся в SEO, гляньте на сайтец, посоветуйте в каком направлении идти дальше?

Вот что было сделано на сайте:

1. Тайтлы страниц, ссылок, Альты изображений
2. SEO тексты в низу страниц категорий
3. Sitemap, robots.txt
4. Дополнительная информация о товаре (торговая марка, отзывы, оценка)
5. Постоянное добавление товаров руками, без парсеров.
6. Попросил всех знакомых, что бы понажимали на гугловскую +1. Где то нашел, что гугл это положительно воспринимает.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопросы по маркетингу и монетизации приложений не относятся к тематике StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Первое. А что, если вы вообще не туда вкладываете силы, время и деньги?

- [Воронка продаж](http://glebarhangelsky.livejournal.com/230808.html)
- [Грустное о продажах](http://glebarhangelsky.livejournal.com/223900.html)

В ситуации с магазином скорее поможет наращивание базы покупателей  (те же холодные звонки) с мягкой рекомендацией пользоваться сайтом. Собственно, вам ведь не толпа посетителей нужна, а **покупатели**, а у покупателей уже есть предпочтения.

Второе. Подумайте над тем, кто ваш покупатель:

> Допустим, я потенциальный покупатель. Я - предприниматель. В каком случае я буду искать канцтовары в интернете? Что может стать причиной смены поставщика (если он у меня уже есть)? Что может побудить меня перестать ходить за бумагой для принтера в магазин на первом этаже офисного здания?

...и (что не менее важно) кто **не ваш** покупатель:

> Через неделю - первое сентября. Тысячи людей закупают тетради и ручки. Это - ваша аудитория?

Захожу на главную и вижу набор товаров, но не вижу специальных предложений (разве что стикер "акция"). Вообще ничего не вижу из того, что могло бы замотивировать меня на моментальную покупку. Посмотрите, как это делают большие магазины, например, [OZON.ru](http://ozon.ru/) - огромная простыня с несколькими поводами купить что-то прямо сейчас.

Comment: Не совсем понял про "не ваш покупатель". Моя аудитория - офисы, не школьники. По поводу главной страницы, то подумаю об этом. Нужно будет туда какие то преимущества запилить.

Comment: @Denis Khvorostin Посмотрите коммент выше

Comment: Попробую высказаться иначе. Ваша аудитория - офисы, но ваш сайт не показывает этого. Поэтому от обслуживания вашей ЦЕЛЕВОЙ аудитории вас будут отрывать по мелочам желающие купить что-то школьники, студенты и пенсионеры (фигурально выражаясь). Так что [фокусируйтесь на своей аудитории](http://www.mann-ivanov-ferber.ru/books/paperbook/the-pumpkin-plan/).

Comment: Спасибо, будем работать над этим)

Answer (score 4):

А какой результат вы ждёте? Я сделал пару целенаправленных запроса в google и ваш сайт попал на первую страницу, что очень не плохо. А если вы ждете, что к вам выстроится очередь клиентов, так тут не в SEO дело. Заинтересуйте ценой и ждите, т.к. на каждый товар найдется свой покупатель. Так как вы не хлебом торгуете, то возможно, что нужна еще какая-то реклама вне инета. Прозвоните организации, школы в вашем городе и т.д. А так, хорошо, что у вас 13-ть видов туалетной бумаги, но лично мне, в голову бы не пришло покупать ее через сайт... до магазина 3 минуты ходьбы ;)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сайт нацелен на офисы компаний, а не на рядовых покупателей

Answer (score 2):

Может быть потенциальным покупателям не нравится то, что вы используете дефолтное оформление из bootstrap'а которое они могли видеть на десятках сайтов? Создаётся впечатление сайта на коленке, что на практике может не совпадать с впечатлением. Немного поменяйте стандартное оформление и сайт уже будет выглядеть иначе!

По поводу SEO: вы по большей части занимались внутренней оптимизацией, но для успешного продвижения огромную роль играет и внешняя. Другими словами, необходимо наращивать ссылочную массу и популяризировать сайт в интернете.

Если переходы есть, а конверсии нет, то я бы вам посоветовал [яндекс вебвизор](http://metrika.yandex.ru/promo), с помощью которого вы можете посмотреть на ваш сайт глазами посетителей и выяснить причины их отказа совершить покупку.

Comment: @Genson пользуюсь вебвизором, но понимания он дает мало. Так же и воронку в ГА сделал, но трудно судить о каких то проблемах, когда в корзину добавляют единицы. Типичный просмотр - это покрутить колесиком туда сюда, полазить по категориям и свалить

Comment: Тогда может быть посетителей не устраивает дизайн/ассортимент/подача/цена. В чём ваше конкурентное преимущество по сравнению с другими магазинами?

Comment: @Genson цены ниже чем у конкурентов. Но я не думаю, что это очень весомо, так как разница в 5-10% особой роли не играет. Доставка от 100 грн бесплатная должна привлекать покупателей.

Answer (score 1):

[@Demyan112rv](/users/7957/demyan112rv), вот этот текст

```
На нашем сайте Вы можете купить канцтовары для офиса в Днепропетровске.
```

я бы вынес на самый верх. Это по крайней мере может привлечь *целевую* аудиторию.

А вообще, не знаю, конечно, какие в Днепропетровске офисы, но на мой взгляд ассортимент какой-то бедненький, размаха не чувствуется.

Т.о. без какого-то броского объявления, которое **сходу** убедило бы меня посмотреть на товары попристальней, я бы через 5 секунд с сайта ушел.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Уже думаю о том, что бы разместить преимущества компании на главной странице.